# Problems with stack and tab navigator in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I noticed some unwanted effects with tab and stack navigator and I can't figure out the problem.
First of all, here's my App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import FirstTab from './react/ui/FirstTab';
import SecondTab from './react/ui/SecondTab';
import ListScreen from './react/ui/ListScreen';

const FirstStack = createStackNavigator({
  FirstTabID: FirstTab,
  ListScreenID: ListScreen,
});

const SecondStack = createStackNavigator({
  SecondTabID: SecondTab,
  ListScreenID: ListScreen,
});

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  FirstTabID: FirstStack,
  SecondTabID: SecondStack,
});

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

This is the FirstTab.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class FirstTab extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'One',
    title: 'My app',
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ListScreenID')}
        title="List"
      />
    ),
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.label}>This is the first tab screen!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
});
```

This is the SecondTab.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class SecondTab extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Two',
    title: 'My app',
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ListScreenID')}
        title="List"
      />
    ),
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.label}>This is the second tab screen!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
});
```

And finally the ListScreen.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class ListScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.label}>And this is the list screen!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
});
```

Ok, what here going wrong is that the tabs are labeled with "first stack" and "second stack". It seems that the navigationOptions.tabBarLabel property of each tab class is completely ignored.
And the second problem is that everytime I tap on the list button in the top right corner, the app crashes instead of showing the list screen.

+++ UPDATED +++

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import FirstTab from './react/ui/FirstTab';
import SecondTab from './react/ui/SecondTab';
import ListScreen from './react/ui/ListScreen';

const FirstStack = createStackNavigator({
  FirstTabID: {
    screen: FirstTab
  }
});

const SecondStack = createStackNavigator({
  SecondTabID: {
    screen: SecondTab
  }
});

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    FirstTabID: {
      screen: FirstStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'One'
      }
    },
    SecondTabID: {
      screen: SecondStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Two'
      }
    }
  }
);

const Navigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Tabs: {
      screen: TabNavigator
    },
    ListScreenID: {
      screen: ListScreen
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Tabs'
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(Navigation);
```

+++ UPDATE FirstTab.js +++

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class FirstTab extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = { (navigation) } => ({
    title: 'My app',
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ListScreenID')}
        title="List"
      />
    ),
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.label}>This is the first tab screen!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
});
```

Comment: Sorry I did not quite understand, do you want to change the BottomTabNavigator label?

Comment: I want to change the text which is displayed on each tab button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the tab label inside the stack and the setting must be set inside the bottomtab.

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    FirstTabID: { 
        screen: FirstStack, 
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'One'
        }
    },
    SecondTabID: { 
        screen: SecondStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Two'
        }
    },
});
```

In this way the label of the tab is defined, the icons are also defined within the bottomtab.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarLabel: 'Two',
    title: 'My app',
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ListScreenID')}
        title="List"
      />
    ),    
})
```

Comment: That was the trick, thanks a lot! Have you also an idea for my other problem, why I can't navigate from the tab view to the next screen in the stack?

Comment: Well this must happen because the tab is the container, you'd better create a stack container and then add the bottomtab inside it and in that same container add the other routes, you need not have problems since all the routes are in the same level.

Comment: I updated my post with the latest code but the problem of navigating to ListScreen still exists.

Comment: What's the problem exactly, do you call navigation from within the guides to lifescreen and nothing happens? If so, add the code snippet in which you call the navigation.

Comment: I already posted the navigation call. Please have a look on FirstTab.js and SecondTab.js in the headerRight attribute.

Comment: I updated the answer, see the section below of the navigationOptions.

Comment: I updated my post with the new FirstTab.js but the app still crashes because the navigation target was not found.